# Not sure why my KeyListener isn't working?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Not entirely sure why this isn't working... I implemented KeyListener and added it to my panel and it is frustrating... The code posted is the only stuff concerning the KeyListener stuff. I have tried all I can using the JFrame to type and moving around all the code to anything that makes sense. I know I have all the correct code because I have looked at about 15 different tutorials and a bunch of questions on here. Please help!

```
public class Dodgem extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{


public Dodgem()
{
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));


    player = new Projectile();       

    counter = 0;
    t = new Timer(5, this);
    t.start();
}



@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println("Key Pressed");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        player.setVelY(-2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        player.setVelY(2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        player.setVelX(-2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        player.setVelX(2);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        player.setVelY(0);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        player.setVelX(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without your [mcve] it's hard to say exactly why it's not working, but I would guess that it's because of the same problems that afflict most all KeyListeners. This question is asked too commonly -- have you [searched this site for common problems associated with KeyListeners](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bswing%5d%20%5bkeylistener%5d%20not%20working) before asking? I have to ask, because you're not showing enough information about your problem to suggest that you have (and you'd probably be using Key Bindings if you did a decent search).

Comment: For example, please look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156033/java-keylistener-isnt-detecting-keyboard-input).

Comment: I tried the code in my IDE and it works fine.

Add a `System.out.println` each time you enter an if to be sure.

I think the problem is maybe the `Projectile` object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyListener not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950726/keylistener-not-working)

Comment: If you've read the top results of the search that I've given you, you already know the best solution: don't use KeyListeners, use Key Bindings. Any Swing expert including myself, camickr, and MadProgrammer will tell you this.

Answer (score -1):

Just looking at the column to the right of this question, you can see there are at least 10 questions titled "KeyListener isn't working?" or something similar. Take a look around before posting.

As for a solution, KeyListeners get events from whatever is in focus, from my experience. Adding them to a JPanel on a JFrame won't return any events, but adding them directly to the JFrame may help.

Comment: I have looked at all of them. The Panel is focused and enabled and the keylistener was added and everything the other questions had problems with

Comment: @Silimerse: again there's no way that we can guess what might be wrong based on the class you've posted. For all we know you could have another component stealing the focus. This sort of information does not help us: `"I know I have all the correct code because I have looked at about 15 different tutorials..."`. You **know** that somewhere your code is incorrect -- if it were correct it work **work**, pure and simple. If you really want to know why **your** implementation KeyListener isn't working, you need to post an [mcve]. Period.

Comment: Did you try my solution? I gave a best guess on the "focus" part but I know from lots of experience that adding the key listener to the window instead of the panel work. Do that.